# Background image not staying in place

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've added a background-img to my section container. Inside that I wan't to create another div, which sits over the top and will include separate img/copy. At the moment if I try and position that div with margin or padding, it is also moving the background image (see whitespace in screenshot).

Is there a way to style this div so I can align it without the background image on the section moving as well? For reference, the 'tree' image is the background image

[image: Screenshot]

```css
  .section__feature {
      background-image: url('/assets/img/hero.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .featured {
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 2rem;
      &__img {
        background-image: url(/assets/img/featured.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 20rem;
      }
    
      grid-area: featured;
    }
```

```html
<section class="section__feature">
        <div class="grid-container">
          <div class="featured">
            <div class="featured__img"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-small-top"></div>
          <div class="feature-small-bottom"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Many thanks

Comment: You can use `top and bottom` properties of css3 as you are using ``position:relative``. hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `background-position: fixed;`  and  `z-index:-1;` on your `.section_feature` if that is your background image.